# Is an impossible proposition necessarily false

Tags: modal-logic

In modal logic, if one **knows** a proposition *p*, then *p* is true (though the converse does not necessarily hold).

Suppose now that *p* is **impossible**. Does that mean that *p* is false (though a false proposition is not necessarily impossible)?

Answer (score 4):

If you agree with the principle :

> **□p→p**,

replacing **p** with **¬p** gives :

> **□¬p→¬p**

that is :

> > **¬◊p→¬p**.

We can red it as :

> if **p** is *impossible*, then **p** is *false*.